# add a class on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a div that I want to remain relative on page until the scroll position reaches the top of the div, then a fixed float is applied via adding a class.

I've got code that I would think should be working; however, cannot get it to do anything.  When scrolling, the div remains relative and won't apply the class to fix the object.

```
$(function() {
  var a = function() {
    var b = $(window).scrollTop();
    var c = $("#header");
      var d = c.offset();


      if(b > d){ alert(d); c.addClass("header-fixed"); }
      else { c.removeClass("header-fixed");  }

};
});
```

This is the CSS

```
.header-fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
#header {
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999998;
}
```

I've got a div above the header that can fluctuate in height so I wanted to calculate the distance from the top of header to the top of the page dynamically.  Whenever the scroll position reaches the position of the top of the div, I want to add class of header-fixed.  If the scroll position goes less than the position, I want to removeClass header-fixed to show the div above the header again.

HTML:

```
<div id="header_container">

<div id="header" class="background-white border-bottom-navy-dark box-shadow-navy-dark">
<div id="header_1" >
<a href="index" class="no-decoration"><img class="logo" src="images/12345.png"  alt=""/>
<div class="display-none-mobile">
<h1 class="title1 color-gold">HEADER 1</h1>
<h2 class="subtitle color-navy-dark">SUB HEADER</h2>
</div>
</div></a>  <?php /*---- header left ----*/ ?>

<div id="header_2">


<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cart-link no-decoration color-gold material-icons">shopping_cart</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="account-link no-decoration color-gold material-icons">person</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-link no-decoration color-gold material-icons">menu</a>




</div>  <?php /*---- header right ----*/ ?>

</div>  <?php /*---- header  ----*/ ?>
</div>  <?php /*---- header site container ----*/ ?>
</div>  <?php /*---- header container ----*/ ?>
```

Comment: Could you please also share the HTML code related to it. That would really help.

Comment: @palaѕн - updated

Comment: Thanks. "_scroll position reaches the top of the div_" which div are you referring to here?

Comment: when the scroll position reaches the top of #header, I want #header to become position fixed.  I can see now where this may cause issues once #header becomes fixed.....hmm

Comment: Ok, my confusion is based on HTML markup you have shared, `#header` seems already at the top inside `header_container`. Is that right?

Comment: I only shared relative html.  There is an announcement div above it that varies in height depending on what we are announcing.  But #header is inside #header_container yes

Comment: regardless, is there anything wrong with my code that may prevent it from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues here like [`c.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns an object. You need to actually use `c.offset().top` instead and you need to add this logic to jquery [`.scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event because right now the check only happens on page load. You need to check for this logic every time window is scrolled.

**Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var c = $("#header");
  var d = c.offset().top - 20;
    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var b = $(window).scrollTop();
    c.toggleClass("header-fixed", b > d);
  });
});
```

```css
.header-fixed{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0}
#header{float:left;width:100%;z-index:9999998}
#announcement{height:500px;border:1px solid #ccc!important;padding:2em;border-radius:10px}
#announcement,#header_container{margin-bottom:15px}
ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #e7e7e7;background-color:#f3f3f3}
li{float:left}
li a{display:block;color:#666;text-align:center;padding:14px 16px;text-decoration:none}
li a.active{color:#fff;background-color:#4CAF50}
.box-shadow-navy-dark { box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #071c38 !important; z-index: 9999999999 !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="announcement">
  Announcement div - Scroll down below
</div>
<div id="header_container">
  <div id="header" class="background-white border-bottom-navy-dark box-shadow-navy-dark">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="announcement">
  Announcement div - Scroll up again
</div>
```

Comment: This code worked perfectly...except....it gets rid of my box shadow effect when page is fully scrolled up.  But when the div goes to position fixed, the box shadow works again.

Comment: `.box-shadow-navy-dark { box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #071c38 !important; z-index: 9999999999 !important; }`

Comment: I have added the css. box-shadow seems to work fine in this demo. There must be some css issue/conflicts at your end.

Comment: I've got an image below it... is it natural for an image to cover a box shadow from a div above it?  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I am not sure about what exactly the issue here is. You can create a new question for it and add a small demo to it to explain the issue. I am sure others would be glad to help.